# Guidebox API alternatives for searching streaming services

Tags: database, api, movie

I found out yesterday that the Guidebox API for retrieving data on shows/movies currently streaming on many of the popular streaming services is moving to pay-only starting in August, and is prohibitive for my budget.

Does anyone know of any alternatives for getting a list of content currently available to stream on various services? (Netflix doesn't necessarily have to be included).  I have searched around without much luck.

Thanks a lot.